# FactoryBot unique constraint violation error, when specifying id in the factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

When a record is created with specified id, subsequent create call fails with unique constraint violation error.

```
Output:

[1]> create(:user, id: 1)
=> #<User:0x00005615116f7378id: 1,created_at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 08:21:04 CEST +02:00,updated_at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 08:21:04 CEST +02:00...

[2]> create(:user)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I would expect FactoryBot to pick up from the last created id and continue on creating. :) What am I missing here? Please advise.

FactoryBot version(as taken from the Gemfile):
factory_bot_rails (5.1.1)
factory_bot (5.1.2)

[edit]

spec/factories/users.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { "Max" }
    last_name { "Mustermann" }
    email_addresses { build_list(:email_address, 1) }
    password { TEST_USER_PASSWORD }
    accepted_terms_of_use { true }
  end
end
```

from db/schema.rb

```rb
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "first_name", limit: 255
  t.string "last_name", limit: 255
  t.string "password_digest", limit: 255
  t.boolean "accepted_terms_of_use", default: false, null: false
end

add_foreign_key "email_addresses", "users"
```

Comment: How do the user factory and migration look like?

Comment: Could you provide a code of your users.rb factory file and the `users` table description?

Comment: Sebastian Palma, Surya I have edited the question to add abbreviated examples of both factory and db table. Do you have any idea what could possibly be causing this? It is not very feasible to provide full factory and exact users description from db/schema.rb. They are just too big.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect FactoryBot to pick up from the last created id and
>   continue on creating. :) What am I missing here?

ID sequences are handed by the database - not FactoryBot. FactoryBot only assigns ids when you use `build_stubbed` to fake persistence.

The solution is really simple - don't hardcode ids. Instead assign your factories to let's / variables and reference them.

Bad:

```
let(:user) { create(:user, id: 1) }

it "does something" do
  get "/users/1"
end
```

Good:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }

it "does something" do
  get user_path(user)
end
```

Comment: Thanks max! I could not agree with you more regarding hardcoding ids. However, this particular codebase relies on one hardcoded id that is specified in the app settings. Refactoring this out is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Then you need to use `User.create_with(attributes_for(:user)).find_or_create_by(id: 1)` to avoid creating a duplicate record.